# Is it possible to get a total number of packets allowed per second via iptables?

Tags: iptables

Is there any way to know the number of packets that are being allowed through iptables every second?

Answer (score 1):

I'm providing two answers for two possible scenarios:

#### If you're asking how to define a rule to limit packets per second

With the default installation of iptables, the rules are stateless, meaning they don't keep track of how many packets are accepted. To start keeping a *counter* of packets that pass through iptables, we'll need to make use of one of its *modules* or perhaps the *quota patch*([see here for how to set that up](https://www.linux-noob.com/forums/topic/3036-bandwidth-quotas-using-iptables/)).

Here, I'll discuss a couple of the "built in" modules you can make use of to set a packet limit per second. For our purposes, there are the `limit` and `conntrack` modules you can make use of to define bandwidth caps. That procedure would consist of creating a new iptables chain:

```
$ sudo iptables --flush  # start again
$ sudo iptables --new-chain RATE-LIMIT
$ sudo iptables --append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW --jump RATE-LIMIT
```

**Explanation:** The `--match` option specifies the module to make use of(we'll specify the use of the `input` module below).

Then, within that chain, create a new rule. In this example, our rule would match no more than 50 packets per second:

```
$ sudo iptables --append RATE-LIMIT --match limit --limit 50/sec --jump ACCEPT
```

The rate-limiting happens when the packets aren't caught by the above rule, in which case, we'll want to drop those packets:

```
$ sudo iptables --append RATE-LIMIT --jump DROP
```

This is just one of the possible ways you can "rate-limit" packets with iptables. For more examples and a lot of great explanation, see [this guide](https://making.pusher.com/per-ip-rate-limiting-with-iptables/).

**Note:** Iptables is a complicated program and requires familiarity with it before proceeding with rules like these. You should start with reading up on [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-deep-dive-into-iptables-and-netfilter-architecture) if you're not yet that comfortable with iptables.

---

#### If you're asking how to simply view the packets that are accepted per second

Getting the packet information in the format that you need(packet/sec) will probably need to be done with a packet sniffer since iptables on its own doesn't have more detailed reporting tools on packets(just simple logging on a packet-by-packet basis). The two most common Linux options are:

**tcpdump**

The `tcpdump` program, like many other linux packet sniffers(including Wireshark), uses the **libpcap** library which looks for packets directly on a network interace(your NIC). If you're interested in viewing the per-second statistics for *all packets*, you can use this quick and dirty method:

```
sudo tcpdump -i <interface-name> -w my-capture.pcap
```

You can leave this running for a while if you want, open a new terminal window and resume your normal network activities. Hit `Ctrl+C` to stop it when you want. This should display some statistics from the capture, including packets "dropped by the kernel". These are packets blocked by iptables. To get a per-second packet rate for all packets(including dropped ones), use the `capinfos` command:

```
capinfos my-capture.pcap
```

You'll get a few lines of output. Look for the `Average packet rate` line.

**Wireshark**

Lastly, you may consider using Wireshark to view this info. It's more sophisticated than tcpdump and has lots of filters available(such as the
[tcp.analysis.lost_segment filter](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/19491/how-do-i-create-filter-for-dropped-packets-and-display-results)) which can show you which packets have been lost on a per-second basis. Note that packet loss isn't always the result of the a firewall. If you're confident your network interface is solid and not losing packets, your data will still be mostly accurate.

To view packet statistics in Wireshark, click on the `Statistics` menu, then select `IO Graph`. See this video for [a demonstration of graphing in Wireshark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2Vg3T14fIA).

---

**Edit:** You mentioned you're developing a Java app to trigger some event when a certain packet-per-second quota is reached. In this case, you should use a networking library for Java like **Pcap4J** which makes use of the same library most linux packet sniffers use. From their github repo:

> Pcap4J is a Java library for capturing, crafting and sending packets.
>   Pcap4J wraps a native packet capture library (libpcap, WinPcap, or
>   Npcap) via JNA and provides you Java-Oriented APIs.

[Here's the site](https://www.pcap4j.org/), with instructions to help you get started.

Comment: Actually I've a java script to perform some action when accepted packets per second is greater than some value. So I need know how to, specifically in java, know the number of total packets allowed through packets (calculate packets per second allowed)

Comment: Edited answer to respond to your comment(see bottom)